# Сокращённое объявление свойства это 2 в 1?(Поле и Свойство но без защиты кода)

Tags: c#, классы, get, set

```
public int Lengthwise { get; set; }
```

Т.е мы могли написать

```
private int leng;// поле

public int Leng

 get{return leng;} 
set{value = value > 0 || value < 10 ? name : name = 0}
```

Но если сокращённый вариант то мы получается не сможем защитить поле(ограничить допустим ввод) потому что у нас нет как такового поля.
Цитирую из книги.

А что, если у вас множество переменных, которые не нуждаются в защите, и им  надо всего лишь создать обертку? Писать столь большое количество кода достаточно накладно. Тут можно использовать сокращенное объявление свойства.   Давайте сокращенным методом объявим глубину сарая:

```
public int Lengthwise { get; set; }
```

В фигурных скобках после ключевых слов get и set нет никакого кода, а сразу стоят точки с запятой. Что это значит? Все очень просто — свойство Lengthwise будет  являться одновременно свойством для внешних источников и переменной для  внутреннего использования. Конечно же, у нас нет кода, а значит, мы не можем   (и просто некуда) добавлять код защиты, поэтому такой метод используется там,  где свойства являются просто оберткой для переменной.

Comment: Вы также можете добавить модификатор доступа на set. Например, `public int LengthWise { get; private set; }`

Comment: Вы плохо читали то, что я писал вам ранее, да и зацикливаетесь сейчас на теории, не пытаясь применить знания на практике. Я вам написал `Разница между свойствами и полями в том, что у свойств есть геттер и сеттер, которым вы можете задать нужные модификаторы доступа по отдельности, а также можете засунуть в них любую логику`, то есть вы можете написать `public int Prop {get;}`, или `public int Prop {get; private set;}`, или `public int Prop {get; init;}`, или `public int Prop {private get; init;}`, вариантов доступа как видите уйма!

Comment: Вообще, свойства нужны только тогда, когда вы хотите ограничить чтение/запись, либо хотите повесить нужную логику при получении/установки значения, ну или если у вас на свойствах завязаны другие механизмы (сериализация, привязки, и так далее), во всех других случаях свойства бесполезны, избыточны. Ну а так, наверно стоит понимать, что свойство - это два метода под капотом, условно `public int Prop {get; set;}` это `public int get_Prop() {}` и `public set_Prop(int val) {}` (вы их даже не сможете создать вместе со свойством), вот и расценивайте свойство как два метода, с их возможностями.

Comment: Я понял что вы писали ранее, и разницу понимаю, просто мне для понимая простым языком для себя хочу определить, свойства выполняют функции доступа к private полям, которые управляют правом доступа к полям, можно так сказать? Или метод с возможностями доступа, логики, ограничений доступа к private  полям

Comment: Не думаю, что эти два описания полностью описывают свойства, они частично затрагивают их функционал, да, но не описывают его полностью. Вот возьмем к примеру полностью раскрытые свойства, обычно это что-то вроде такого: `private int _value; public int Value { get => _value; set => _value = value; }`, ну и как-бы вопрос - а кто нам мешает сделать `private int _value` публичным? Да, это не правильно, такого быть не должно, но это возможно. Просто расценивайте свойство как некий объект (обычно поле) с двумя методами в удобной обертке, вот и все)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас всё смешалось, при чём здесь вообще защита и поля? Свойство это спаренные 2 метода, геттер и сеттер.

Представьте себе 2 метода

```
public int GetNumber()
{
    return 42;
}

public void SetNumber(int value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Ничего необычного, правда? А теперь сделаю это в виде свойства

```
public int Number
{
    get
    {
        return 42;
    }
    set
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Поняли, что происходит? Поля нет вообще. Свойства - это популярный шаблон проектирования в ООП. Когда не было свойств, разработчики писали методы-геттеры и методы-сеттеры отдельно.

Как вы уже верно догадались, сеттер можно использовать для защиты внутреннего состояния объекта, а геттер - для преобразования отдаваемых данных.

Свойство может всё то же самое, что могут методы: иметь модификаторы доступа, выполнить любой код, ведь вы из геттера и сеттера можете вызвать совершенно любой метод в приложении или создать класс, или бросить исключение, никаких ограничений на выполнение кода в свойстве нет.

Единственное требование к геттеру, это то что метод-геттер должен иметь возвращаемое значение, по типу равное типу свойства и не иметь аргументов, сеттер напротив не имеет возвращаемого значения, но имеет один единственный аргумент `value`, тип которого соответствует типу свойства.

Теперь, что такое автосвойство. Иногда нужно просто принять и передать данные наружу из одного единственного поля, ничего с ними не делая, но иметь возможность задать геттеру и сеттеру модификаторы доступа.

И чтобы не писать каждый раз вот это

```
private int number;

public int Number
{
    get => number;
    set => number = value;
}
```

Используют сокращённую запись

```
public int Number { get; set; }
```

Давайте посмотрим, во что превращает автосвойство компилятор перед тем как сгенерировать код на промежуточном языке (IL), он его разворачивает в обычное свойство.

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private int <Number>k__BackingField;

public int Number
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    get
    {
        return <Number>k__BackingField;
    }
    [CompilerGenerated]
    set
    {
        <Number>k__BackingField = value;
    }
}
```

Декомпилированный код выглядит грязнее, чем я выше пример показал, но по логике это совершенно то же самое, никакой магии.

Свойство - это 2 логически спаренных метода: геттер и сеттер. Ключевое слово здесь "метода".

Ещё стоит знать, что свойство может быть только с геттером без сеттера, или только с сеттером без геттера. Последний вариант встречается редко.

*Каждый раз обращаясь к свойству, вы выполняете его геттер. Каждый раз присваивая значение свойству, вы выполняете его сеттер.*

---

**Бонус**

Ах, да, ещё одно ограничение: геттер и сеттер не могут иметь модификатор `async`, то есть быть асинхронными.

Для душнил :D напишу, что технически геттер может быть асинхронным, то есть возвращать awaitable тип, а сеттер не может, так как он ничего не возвращает.

Пример асинхронного геттера

```
public Task<int> NumberAsync
{
    get => CreateNumberAsync();
}

private async Task<int> CreateNumberAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    return 42;
}
```

Можно асинхронно выполнить этот геттер

```
int number = await NumberAsync;
```

Это ещё раз доказывает, что свойства могут ровно всё то же самое, что и методы.

---

Если всё поняли, то посмотрите на пример кода в самом начале ответа, где свойство без поля. Вопрос: что произойдёт, если я напишу вот такой код?

```
Number++;
```